# Is it possible to delete figures or shapes in Html5, or php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

My project requires me to create few circles on a browser and it must allow the users to delete any circle of their choice and the deleted information must be stored I can do this using servlets, right?(storing the information of just the deleting part) These are my requirements.

Could anyone guide me to what is the technology that I will be needing to implement this?
should i go for html5 or php or javascript?

Comment: Use [jQuery's Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com).  This way you can send data to a PHP file onclick or whatever.

Comment: Ok then jQuery, Ajax and php Using these technologies I can get my work done right.

Comment: Sounds like you need HTML and JS. PHP is optional. HTML for content, JS for interaction. You could use JS to store which shapes were deleted but your data will only last for that session. If you want it to last longer use PHP/MySQL

Comment: @stackErr I need the information just for session. Will I be able to select a shape and delete it. using mouse or keybord, with the help of JS(Java Script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a handler for some event on the circle in jQuery.
In the handler, you could just store an attribute + delete the element.
And then send an AJAX POST request to the server.

This is one way to do it:

```
$('.circle').on('click', function() {
  dat = $(this).attr('dat'); // Get the data from an HTML attribute
  $(this).remove();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/_removedCircle',
    data: {'data': dat}
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you.. Then I have a lot to learn, Html, jQuery and Ajax :)